# Fast way to figure out if a number is inside a vector in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I was hoping to figure out a fast way to find out if a number is contained within a vector for the purpose of passing it to an if statement.  So far, the best I have come up with is the following:

```
a = 5
b = 1:10

if(length(which(a==5)) > 0){

#Do something...

}
```

I'm sure there is a faster way of doing this.

Comment: `if (a %in% b)`

Comment: Make that a solution and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%in%`:

```
if (a %in% b) ...
```

This may not necessarily be *faster* than what you've got (since it's just syntactic sugar for a `match` call) but it's certainly more compact and transparent.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is to use `any(a == b)`:

```
library(microbenchmark)
options(digits = 3)

a <- 5
b <- 1:10

microbenchmark(
  length(which(a == b)) > 0, 
  a %in% b,
  any(a == b)
)
# Unit: nanoseconds
#                       expr  min   lq median   uq  max neval
#  length(which(a == b)) > 0 1328 1414   1472 1587 5765   100
#                   a %in% b 1519 1690   1773 1864 6665   100
#                any(a == b)  662  728    786  844 6205   100
```

But I'd agree that `a %in% b` is more clear, and it's unlikely saving 1 µs will have a noticeable impact on your code.

Also note that any of these methods will only work for characters and integers, not floating point numbers, and only when `a` is a scalar.

Comment: To protect the innocent: this only works when a is not a vector.